# python asynchronous data pull error: __aexit__/__enter__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, exasol

I am trying to write code leveraging async functionality of Python. I have a DB connection class where I have code for (dis)connecting with DB and also for fetching the data. Now I want to asynchronously fetch data using fetch data method based on one identifier. Code is as shown below:

```
import pyexasol
import pandas as pd
import logging
from typing import Iterable
import asyncio
import tqdm


class Exa(object):
    def __init__(self, dsn: str = '1.2.3.4',
                 user: str = os.environ['UID'],
                 password: str = os.environ['PWD']):
        self.__dsn = dsn
        self.__user = user
        self.__password = password
        self.conn = None

    def __connect(self):
        if self.conn is None:
            try:
                self.conn = pyexasol.connect(dsn=self.__dsn, user=self.__user,
                    password=self.__password, encryption=True)
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Error in connecting with Exasol. Error is: {e}")

    def __disconnect(self):
        if self.conn is not None:
            try:
                self.conn.close()
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Exception in disconnecting DB. Error is {e}")
            self.conn = None

    def fetch(self, query: str, leave_connection_open: bool = False) -> pd.DataFrame:
        # connect and execute the query
        self.__connect()
        try:
            res = self.conn.export_to_pandas(query)
            res.columns = res.columns.str.lower()
        except Exception as e:
            self.__disconnect()
            return pd.DataFrame()
        if not leave_connection_open:
            self.__disconnect()
        return res

    def fetch_batch(self, pattern: str, replacement: Iterable,
                    query: str, batchsize: int = 5000) -> pd.DataFrame:
        res = asyncio.run(self._fetch_batch(pattern=pattern, replacement=replacement,
                                            query=query, batchsize=batchsize))
        return res

    async def _fetch_batch(self, pattern: str, replacement: Iterable,
                           query: str, batchsize: int = 5000) -> pd.DataFrame:

        replacement = list(replacement)
        # breaking into batches
        if any(isinstance(i, str) for i in replacement):
            batches = ["'" + "','".join(replacement[i:i + batchsize]) + "'"
                       for i in range(0, len(replacement), batchsize)]
        else:
            batches = [",".join(replacement[i:i + batchsize])
                       for i in range(0, len(replacement), batchsize)]
        # connecting and executing query in batches
        nbatches = len(batches)
        self.__connect()
        try:
            tasks = [self.__run_batch_query(query=query.replace(pattern, batches[i]),
                                            i=i, nbatches=nbatches) for i in range(nbatches)]
            # progress bar
            res = [await f for f in tqdm.tqdm(asyncio.as_completed(tasks), total=len(tasks))]
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("Could not fetch batches of data. Error is: %s", e)
        '''finally:
            self.__disconnect()'''
        # dataframe concatenation
        res = pd.concat(res)
        res.columns = res.columns.str.lower()
        return res

    async def __run_batch_query(self, query: str,
                                i: int, nbatches: int) -> pd.DataFrame:
        logging.info("Fetching %d/%d", i + 1, nbatches)
        async with self.fetch(query=query, leave_connection_open=True) as resp:
            raw = await resp
        return raw
```

I am running this code with:

```
from foo import Exa
db = Exa()

ids = db.fetch('select id from application limit 100')
ids1 = db.fetch_batch(pattern='IDS',
                         replacement=ids['id'],
                         query='select id from application where id in (IDS)',
                         batchsize=25)
```

but then I get error like:

```
ERROR:root:Could not fetch batches of data. Error is: __aexit__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/priya/pydbutils/gitignored/foo2.py", line 85, in __run_batch_query
    async with self.fetch(query=query, leave_connection_open=True) as resp:
AttributeError: __aexit__
```

Also if I change `__run_batch_query()` method call to `self.fetch()` method without `async` then error changes to:

```
ERROR:root:Could not fetch batches of data. Error is: __enter__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/priya/pydbutils/gitignored/foo2.py", line 85, in __run_batch_query
    with self.fetch(query=query, leave_connection_open=True) as resp:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

please help by pointing out the mistake if any here?

Comment: `fetch` isn't a context manager. Just call it regularly `resp = self.fetch(...)`. It isn't asyncio-aware, so asyncio won't really provide you with any value here.

Comment: What dirn said. You might still make things better by replacing `async with self.fetch(...)` with `raw = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: self.fetch(...))`. Fetching will be done in a thread pool, but the rest of the application can use asyncio (if that's a goal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyexasol creator is here.

Please note, asyncio will not provide any benefits for Exasol-related scenarios. Ayncio runs on single CPU and utilises single network connection, which prevents any meaningful scaling.

The the most efficient ways to load data from Exasol server are:

- `export_to_pandas()` or `export_to_callback()` for single Python process;
- `export_parallel()` + `http_transport()` for multiple Python processes;

Please check `HTTP Transport (parallel)` manual page for explanations and examples. This approach scales linearly, and you may even run the computation tasks on multiple servers.

For simple scenarios, you may consider `compression=True` connection option if you transfer large amounts of data over slow (e.g. WiFi) network.

Comment: Could you please explain why `Asyncio utilises single network connection`?

Comment: Exasol WebSocket protocol can only execute one command at a time. It includes both SQL query execution of fetching. Asyncio will not help to scale this up. It will be blocked in waiting on protocol level.

The only ways to scale this up are (either):
1) Open multiple connections;
2) Use parallel HTTP transport to read dataset of one SQL query in parallel;